# Automatic casting in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a class that inherits the Actor trait.  In my code, I have a method that creates `x` numbers of this actor using a loop and another method that simply sends the Finish message to all of them to tell them to terminate.  I made the kill method just take an array of Actor since I want to be able to use it with an array of any type of Actor.  For some reason, however, when I pass a value of type Array[Producer], where Producer extends Actor, to a method that accepts the type Array[Actor], I get a type error.  Shouldn't Scala see that Producer is a type of Actor and automatically cast this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing is called *covariance*, and it is a property of most of the collection classes in Scala--a collection of a subtype is a subtype of the collection of the supertype.  However, since `Array` is a Java primitive array, it is not covariant--a collection of a subtype is simply different.  (The situation is more complicated in 2.7 where it's *almost* a Java primitive array; in 2.8 Array is just a plain Java primitive array, since the 2.7 complications turned out to have unfortunate corner cases.)

If you try the same thing with an `ArrayBuffer` (from `collection.mutable` <- edit: this part is wrong, see comments) or a `List` (<- edit: this is true) or a `Set` (<- edit: no, `Set` is also invariant), you'll get the behavior you want.  You could also create an `Array[Actor]` to begin with but always feed it `Producer` values.

If for some reason you really must use `Array[Producer]`, you can still cast it using `.asInstanceOf[Array[Actor]]`.  But I suggest using something other than primitive arrays--anything you could possibly be doing with actors will be far slower than the tiny overhead of using a more full-featured collection class.

Comment: I just changed my Array's to mutable.ArrayBuffer's, but am still getting the same casting issue.  BTW, I'm using Scala 2.7.7.

Comment: However, switching the collection objects to contain Actor instead of my subclasses seems to have fixed things up.

Comment: Whoops--I forgot that a lot of the `mutable` collection is invariant.  `immutable.Vector` would work, though.

Comment: I should add that with the mutable collections, the invariance is there for good reason.  Suppose you have an `Array[Producer]`, pass it to a function that takes an `Array[Actor]`, that function puts some actors in it that are _not_ `Producers`, and then you use your array again.  You think it's all `Producers`, but it's not!  If the thing was immutable, that last step (they change it and you don't realize) is impossible, so it's not a concern, so the collection can be covariant.  But with mutable collections, it's your job to make it broad enough to start (e.g. as `Array[Actor]`).